# jQuery Event for link click not firing

Tags: jquery

I have the following function:

```
  $("a#mylink").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $.ajax({ url: $(this).attr("href") }); 
            $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut("slow");
          });
```

A link is being created on the page with the following code:

```
'<div  style="margin-top: 4px; border: solid 2px #515151; color: #515151; width: 300px;"><span style="padding-left: 4px">' +
                file.name+
                '    </span><div style="float: right; padding-right: 4px;"><a class="mylink" href="remove.aspx?img='+safeUrl+'">Remove</a></div>' +
                '</div>'
```

When I click the link, a new page pops up and it does not hit my function.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.mylink` not `a#mylink`

# is the ID selector, and you have mylink set as a class.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting "mylink" in the "class" but your selector is looking for an "id" value. Try:

```
$('a.mylink').click( ... )
```

or else use "mylink" as the "id" value for the anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

This link is being added dynamically? Sounds like you need to use `live()`

```
// incidentally, drop the "a" from "a.mylink" it's unnecessary and slows it down
$(".mylink").live('click', function () { ... });
```

As the others saw (and I didn't) `#xyz` matches an `id`, whereas `.xyz` matches a `class`. You have a `class` on your link, so you need to use a dot.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that since I was adding my link durning run-time, I needed to re-bind my click event.